# How to solve a saturation problem with AWS EC2 t2.micro

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, saturation-arithmetic

Instance t2.micro
Detail : ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20200716

Hello I run a python script on a EC2 instance. It is a very simple script which extract data from a webpage.
My instance overloads very quickly.

Here are some charts of the monitoring :

[image]

[image]

How can I setting up perfectly the instance for a ongoing run of the instance ?

Comment: What makes you think it's overloaded?

Comment: Your exhausting your CPU credits. You can try a t3.micro, which shouldn't suffer from the issue, but it will be a little more expensive.

Comment: @jingx CPU credit balance

Comment: Any burstable instance will suffer the same problem, as long as the required CPU is greater than the available CPU. You can enable "T2/T3 Unlimited", but you'll end up paying more than a low-end steady-state instance unless your script doesn't run all of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. currently I am using the free trial of AWS, is it possible to unlock the instance to ensure that the instance becomes unlimited

Comment: There is no "free trial" of AWS, there is a "free tier" in certain services. If you stay below the usage requirements of the free tier then you don't get charged. The EC2 instance is not "locked", you are capable of increasing the size or enabling the T2/T3 unlimited setting, however that will go outside the "free tier" restrictions and Amazon will begin charging you.